# Getting Model Data from DropDown List Selection ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating a costing web application for uni and work.

I have a form which has a drop down selection, which is generated from my model data.

My model data

```
public class CoreSheets
{
    [Key] 
    public int sheetID { get; set; }
    public string Abb { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfPrice { get; set; }
    public int Hardness { get; set; }
}
```

View Data for the dropdownlist

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <form>
     @Html.DropDownList("selectedSheetOD", (SelectList)ViewBag.Sheets)
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Iflexcst()
{
  CoreSheetsDBContext db = new CoreSheetsDBContext();
  ViewBag.Sheets = new SelectList(db.CoreSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");
  return View(db.CoreSheets.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Iflexcst(int kammid, int kammod, FormCollection form)
{
  ViewBag.Sheets = new SelectList(db.CoreSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");
  long DropDownSelection = Convert.ToInt64(form["selectedSheetOD"]);
  ViewBag.Result = (kammid * kammod) / (3000 * 1500) * DropDownSelection;
  return View();
}
```

So if you are still following (hopefully face), I want the user to select a sheet from the drop down and then from their selection it pulls the sheets length and width into the calculation from the database "ViewBag.Result = (kammid * kammod) / (3000 * 1500) " rather than the 3000 * 1500

Comment: Start by removing the manual `<form>` tags (your generating nested forms which is invalid html). What are `kammid` and `kammod` - you don't generate any controls for them so they will always be zero

Comment: Hi i didnt include the whole of the form due to it been long, 


        Kamm ID:<br>
        <input id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />
        <br> Kamm OD: <br>
        <input id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />

        <br>
They are just two text fields, user inputs the outer dimension and inner dimension which is then passed to the controller

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass `kammid` and `kammod` - Are these not the values you want from the db?

Comment: The dropdown list contains a list of sheets 

 ViewBag.Sheets = new SelectList(db.CoreSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");

I want the selection by the user to get the length of width from the database of that sheet, and use this in my action method, rather than 3000, 1500. Kamm OD & Kamm ID are user input values.

Comment: If you wanting the `Length` and `Width` properties of the selected `CoreSheets`, then you need to get them from the repository again.

Comment: Haha yes its simple in theory i just dont know how,,

User specifies a KAMM 150 BY 200, Says they want it to be stainless steel, so the action method needs to do 150 * 200 / Selected sheet length * Selected Sheet width. This is then outputted in viewbag result?

Comment: `var selectedCoreSheet = db.CoreSheets.Where(c => c.sheetID = DropDownSelection).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help BTW.

So would i just use like "selectedCoreSheet.length" in the formula ?

And im getting an error of Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int?'

Comment: Exactly. And `sheetID` is typeof `int` so why are you doing `long DropDownSelection = Convert.ToInt64(form["selectedSheetOD"]);` in should be `int DropDownSelection = ...`. But you really need to learn some basics of MVC and create a view model, use strongly typed helpers to bind to the model, and post back the model.

Comment: Right ive changed it to  int DropDownSelection = Convert.ToInt32(form["selectedSheetOD"]);

But now it has the same issue but within "var selectedCoreSheet = db.CoreSheets.Where(c => c.sheetID = DropDownSelection).FirstOrDefault()" it says can not convert type int to bool. :(

Comment: Sorry, typo i my previous comment - its `c => c.sheetID == DropDownSelection`

Comment: i get this error now :( 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: THink i just fixxed it,,,,

Comment: Stephen Muecke, you are the best. I said my love from yorkshire in the UK <3